# Three-dimensional TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows

I have used an online TikZ-generator to draw a three-dimensional model of a pontoon. This resulted in the following model:[image: Screenshot]

The generated code:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
% Defining TikZ-package libraries
% -------------------------------------------
\usetikzlibrary{intersections,
                calc,
                fit,
                angles}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                patterns,
                pgfplots.fillbetween}
% -------------------------------------------

% Adjust pgfplots package
% -------------------------------------------
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17} % Always used with pgfplots-package.
\pgfdeclarelayer{ft} % Front layer.
\pgfdeclarelayer{bg} % Background layer.
\pgfsetlayers{bg,main,ft} % Set of all the layers. Main is defined as standard.
% -------------------------------------------
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.75pt,y=0.75pt,yscale=-1,xscale=1]
%uncomment if require: \path (0,321); %set diagram left start at 0, and has height of 321

%Shape: Can [id:dp5717673127119256] 
\draw   (512.96,68.1) -- (530.61,117.73) .. controls (535.48,131.43) and (439.8,177.96) .. (316.9,221.65) .. controls (194,265.34) and (90.42,289.65) .. (85.55,275.94) -- (67.91,226.31) .. controls (63.04,212.61) and (158.72,166.08) .. (281.61,122.39) .. controls (404.51,78.7) and (508.09,54.4) .. (512.96,68.1) .. controls (517.84,81.8) and (422.16,128.33) .. (299.26,172.02) .. controls (176.36,215.71) and (72.78,240.02) .. (67.91,226.31) ;
%Shape: Axis 2D [id:dp10413797801144087] 
\draw  (272.9,157.55) -- (367.95,126.49)(254.45,68.9) -- (285.51,163.95) (359.75,123.91) -- (367.95,126.49) -- (362.85,133.41) (251.87,77.11) -- (254.45,68.9) -- (261.37,74)  ;
%Straight Lines [id:da8625336310449667] 
\draw    (269.41,152.45) -- (351.17,165.12) ;
\draw [shift={(353.14,165.43)}, rotate = 188.81] [color={rgb, 255:red, 0; green, 0; blue, 0 }  ][line width=0.75]    (10.93,-3.29) .. controls (6.95,-1.4) and (3.31,-0.3) .. (0,0) .. controls (3.31,0.3) and (6.95,1.4) .. (10.93,3.29)   ;
%Curve Lines [id:da48312758037302217] 
\draw    (258.14,103.43) .. controls (282.27,99.57) and (271.94,80.81) .. (252.31,95.68) ;
\draw [shift={(250.14,97.43)}, rotate = 319.4] [fill={rgb, 255:red, 0; green, 0; blue, 0 }  ][line width=0.08]  [draw opacity=0] (8.93,-4.29) -- (0,0) -- (8.93,4.29) -- cycle    ;
%Curve Lines [id:da5961405573248826] 
\draw    (329,133.43) .. controls (327.05,111) and (364.08,159.88) .. (334.41,144.72) ;
\draw [shift={(332,143.43)}, rotate = 389.2] [fill={rgb, 255:red, 0; green, 0; blue, 0 }  ][line width=0.08]  [draw opacity=0] (8.93,-4.29) -- (0,0) -- (8.93,4.29) -- cycle    ;
%Curve Lines [id:da970701558271948] 
\draw    (321.14,157.43) .. controls (331.87,143.78) and (281.89,154.84) .. (311.69,163.75) ;
\draw [shift={(314.14,164.43)}, rotate = 194.48] [fill={rgb, 255:red, 0; green, 0; blue, 0 }  ][line width=0.08]  [draw opacity=0] (8.93,-4.29) -- (0,0) -- (8.93,4.29) -- cycle    ;

% Text Node
\draw (373.6,122.38) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]  [rotate=-341.32] [align=left] {{\small surge}};
% Text Node
\draw (325,104) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]   [align=left] {{\small \textcolor[rgb]{0.82,0.01,0.11}{roll}}};
% Text Node
\draw (334.94,166.59) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]  [font=\small,rotate=-11.44] [align=left] {{\small sway}};
% Text Node
\draw (227.61,54.51) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]  [rotate=-343.32] [align=left] {{\small heave}};
% Text Node
\draw (275.96,93.09) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]  [rotate=-334.26] [align=left] {{\small \textcolor[rgb]{0.82,0.01,0.11}{yaw}}};
% Text Node
\draw (289.21,177.95) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]  [font=\small,rotate=-338.93] [align=left] {{\small \textcolor[rgb]{0.82,0.01,0.11}{pitch}}};
% Text Node
\draw (365.69,108.23) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]  [rotate=-340.94] [align=left] {x*};
% Text Node
\draw (355,153) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]   [align=left] {y*};
% Text Node
\draw (262.82,61.85) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]  [rotate=-341.17] [align=left] {z*};


\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Although this figure may work well enough for my purpose I want to make some small adjustments and also to be able to generate this figure from scratch using TikZ.

How can I create the three-dimensional ellipse, the axes and the curved arrows around these?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a possibility. It's not exactly your perspective but an isometric one, which is easier to draw (specifically the cylinder). You can use the options `canvas is ... plane at ...` form tikz 3d library and this way you can draw the ellipses and the arrow arcs (roll, pitch and yaw).

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage    {tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{3d}    % for 'canvas is...' options
\usetikzlibrary{babel} % there are some issues with tikz and some babel packages

% isometric axes
\pgfmathsetmacro\xx{1/sqrt(2)}
\pgfmathsetmacro\xy{1/sqrt(6)}
\pgfmathsetmacro\zy{sqrt(2/3)}

% styles
\tikzset%
{%
       axis/.style={thick,-latex},
  axis node/.style={transform shape,right,midway,sloped,xshift=0.6cm},
  arc arrow/.style={magenta,midway,right},
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,% isometric axes:
                    x={(\xx cm,\xy cm)},y={(\xx cm,-\xy cm)},z={(0 cm,\zy cm)},%
                    rotate=10] % but rotated 10 degrees anticlockwise
% definitions
\def\r{3.5}   % cylinder radius
\def\h{1}     % cylinder height
\def\lr{0.25} % little radius for the arrow arcs
% axes
\draw[axis] (0,0,0) -- (0.5*\r,0,0) node [axis node]             {$\mathrm{x}^*$ surge};
\draw[axis] (0,0,0) -- (0,0.5*\r,0) node [axis node]             {$\mathrm{y}^*$ sway};
\draw[axis] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,\r)     node [transform shape,above] {$\mathrm{z}^*$ heave};
% cylinder
\draw (0,0) circle (\r);
\draw (45:\r) --++ (0,0,-\h) arc (45:225:\r) --++ (0,0,\h);
% roll, pitch and yaw arrows
\draw[canvas is xy plane at z=0.5*\r ,->] (180:\lr) arc (180:-90:\lr) node [arc arrow]            {yaw};
\draw[canvas is xz plane at y=0.25*\r,->] (-90:\lr) arc (-90:180:\lr) node [arc arrow,pos=1,left] {pitch};
\draw[canvas is yz plane at x=0.25*\r,->] (180:\lr) arc (180:-90:\lr) node [arc arrow]            {roll};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit:** The pontoon needed an elliptic section. As said, the tangent generatrices will be very difficult to draw in isometric perspective (and any other perspective for that matter). I offer a workaround, drawing an oval instead of an ellipse. I follow the method for an isometric oval (it could be any other oval, the perspective here is not important as I'm drawing a 2d oval in a horizontal plane). To better see the method I'm using you can uncomment the rhombus lines in the code. This way again the tangents are between circles and it's easy to determine the tangent points.

I added the tikz library `calc` as I need to compute a couple of coordinates. I also changed the axis like in the OP solution.

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage    {tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{3d}    % for 'canvas is...' options
\usetikzlibrary{babel} % there are some issues with tikz and some babel packages
\usetikzlibrary{calc}  % computes coordinates

% isometric axes
\pgfmathsetmacro\xx{1/sqrt(2)}
\pgfmathsetmacro\xy{1/sqrt(6)}
\pgfmathsetmacro\zy{sqrt(2/3)}

% styles
\tikzset%
{%
       axis/.style={thick,-latex},
  axis node/.style={transform shape,right,midway,sloped,xshift=0.6cm},
  arc arrow/.style={magenta,midway,right},
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,% isometric axes:
                    x={(\xx cm,-\xy cm)},y={(\xx cm,\xy cm)},z={(0 cm,\zy cm)},%
                    rotate=10] % but rotated 10 degrees anticlockwise
% definitions
\def\r{3.5}   % cylinder radius
\def\h{1}     % cylinder height
\def\lr{0.25} % little radius for the arrow arcs
% axes
\draw[axis] (0,0,0) -- (0.5*\r,0,0) node [axis node]             {$\mathrm{x}^*$ surge};
\draw[axis] (0,0,0) -- (0,0.5*\r,0) node [axis node]             {$\mathrm{y}^*$ sway};
\draw[axis] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,\r)     node [transform shape,above] {$\mathrm{z}^*$ heave};
% pontoon
\def\l{4} % rhombus semi-lenght (the rhombus is circumscribed to the pontoon, see below)
\begin{scope}[canvas is xy plane at z=0]
  \coordinate (A) at ({sqrt(3)*\l},0);
  \coordinate (B) at (0,\l);
  \coordinate (C) at ({-sqrt(3)*\l},0);
  \coordinate (D) at (0,-\l);
  \coordinate (P) at ($(A)!0.5!(B)$); % only needed in the rhombus
  \coordinate (Q) at ($(B)!0.5!(C)$); % only needed in the rhombus
  \coordinate (R) at ($(C)!0.5!(D)$); % only needed in the rhombus
  \coordinate (S) at ($(D)!0.5!(A)$);
  \coordinate (T) at ($1/3*(A)+1/3*(B)+1/3*(D)+(45:{\l/sqrt(3)})$);
  \draw (S) arc (-60: 60:{\l/sqrt(3)}) arc ( 60:120:{sqrt(3)*\l})
            arc (120:240:{\l/sqrt(3)}) arc (240:300:{sqrt(3)*\l});
\end{scope}
\draw (T) --++ (0,0,-\h) arc (45:-60:{\l/sqrt(3)}) arc (-60:-120:{sqrt(3)*\l}) arc (-120:-135:{\l/sqrt(3)}) --++ (0,0,\h);
% rhombus (uncomment to see)
%\draw[red] (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- (D) -- cycle;
%\draw[red] (P) -- (D) -- (Q);
%\draw[red] (R) -- (B) -- (S);
% roll, pitch and yaw arrows
\draw[canvas is xy plane at z=0.5*\r ,->] (180:\lr) arc (180:-90:\lr) node [arc arrow]            {yaw};
\draw[canvas is xz plane at y=0.25*\r,->] (180:\lr) arc (180:-90:\lr) node [arc arrow,yshift=-2mm]{pitch};
\draw[canvas is yz plane at x=0.25*\r,->] (-90:\lr) arc (-90:180:\lr) node [arc arrow,pos=1,left] {roll};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]
In my opinion the picture would look better with a vertical z-axis. To get this just remove the `rotate=10` in the `tikzpicture` options. You'll get this.
[image]

Comment: Nice! I think your perspective was better actually. However, I think the pontoon should be a little bit more elongated, a bit more elliptic form.

Comment: @thisismetrying. If the pontoon is circular (I don't know what a pontoon is) it should look this way in isometric perspective. Of course, you can change the axis for getting the figure more "elliptical", but then the tangent generatices will be more difficult to place.

Comment: See my answer below for (almost) what I want to achieve.

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you for your thorough answer!

Answer (score 0):

I made some changes to your proposed solution, Juan. I replaced the circle with an ellipse and used layers in the drawing. I got something similar to what I want to achieve:[image: Screenshot] However, as you mention the tangent generatices is not quite there yet. Also, the axis system seems to be a bit inclined. I'm not quite sure how to fix this though.

The code:

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage    {tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{3d}    % for 'canvas is...' options
\usetikzlibrary{babel} % there are some issues with tikz and some babel packages

% Adjust pgfplots package
% -------------------------------------------
\pgfdeclarelayer{ft} % Front layer.
\pgfdeclarelayer{bg} % Background layer.
\pgfsetlayers{bg,main,ft} % Set of all the layers. Main is defined as standard.
% -------------------------------------------
\pgfsetlayers{bg,main,ft}

% isometric axes
\pgfmathsetmacro\xx{1/sqrt(2)}
\pgfmathsetmacro\xy{1/sqrt(6)}
\pgfmathsetmacro\zy{sqrt(2/3)}

% styles
\tikzset%
{%
       axis/.style={thick,-latex},
  axis node/.style={transform shape,right,midway,sloped,xshift=0.6cm},
  arc arrow/.style={magenta,midway,right},
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,% isometric axes:
                    x={(\xx cm,\xy cm)},y={(\xx cm,-\xy cm)},z={(0 cm,\zy cm)},%
                    rotate=10] % but rotated 10 degrees anticlockwise
% definitions
\def\r{3.5}   % cylinder radius
\def\h{1}     % cylinder height
\def\lr{0.25} % little radius for the arrow arcs
\begin{pgfonlayer}{ft}
    % axes
    \draw[axis] (0,0,0) -- (0,0.5*\r,0) node [axis node] {$\mathrm{x}^*$ surge};
    \draw[axis] (0,0,0) -- (0.5*\r,0,0) node [axis node] {$\mathrm{y}^*$ sway};
    \draw[axis] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,\r) node [transform shape,above] {$\mathrm{z}^*$ heave};
    % roll, pitch and yaw arrows
    \draw[canvas is xy plane at z=0.5*\r ,->] (180:\lr) arc (180:-90:\lr) node [arc arrow]            {yaw};
    \draw[canvas is xz plane at y=0.25*\r,->] (-90:\lr) arc (-90:180:\lr) node [arc arrow,pos=1,left] {roll};
    \draw[canvas is yz plane at x=0.25*\r,->] (180:\lr) arc (180:-90:\lr) node [arc arrow]            {pitch};
\end{pgfonlayer}
    % cylinder
\draw [fill=white] (0,0) ellipse [x radius=3, y radius=6];
\begin{pgfonlayer}{bg}
    \draw (0,0,-\h) ellipse [x radius=3, y radius=6];
\end{pgfonlayer}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Any suggestions on the final parts?